# Reference for example of gradient steady Ricci solitons

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Recently I read a [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.matpur.2016.10.007) about Ricci solitons. I quote a paragraph of it here:

> In dimension three, the classification of complete gradient steady Ricci solitons is still open. ***Known examples are given by quotients of $\Bbb R^3$, $\Sigma^2×\Bbb R$ and the rotationally symmetric one constructed by Bryant***. In the paper by Brendle, it was shown that the Bryant soliton is the only nonflat, $k$-noncollapsed, steady soliton, proving a famous conjecture by Perelman.

Apart from known example of Prof. Bryant, the authors of the above paper have not provided any references for bolded examples. Does anyone know where can I find this examples?

Comment: The default answer for Ricci flow questions like this is: have you checked one of Ben Chow's books? If not, look there first!